# how can I access List type of data in django

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

client side, I sent a JSON data including list type data like this.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: '/man/manual',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {'id':'','title':'ttt','description':'desc','steps':[{'title':'1'},{'title':'2'}]},
     dataType : 'JSON',
     success : function(data) {
         console.log(data);
     }
 });
```

I tried to access these data.

```
title = request.POST['title']
description = request.POST['description']
steps = request.POST['steps']

for step in steps:
    print(step.title)
```

but I got an error.

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response

132. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view

71. return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
89. return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/sangwonlee/Makewith/trunk/MW_Service/mw_manual/views.py" in post
77. self.createManual(request)
File "/Users/sangwonlee/Makewith/trunk/MW_Service/mw_manual/views.py" in createManual
27. steps = request.POST['steps']
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
322. raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /man/manual
Exception Value: "'steps'"
Request information:
GET: No GET data

POST:
description = 'desc'
steps[1][title] = '2'
steps[0][title] = '1'
title = 'ttt'
id = ''
```

How can I change my to code for correct data from client side.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get the list with the requested key, use `getlist` method.

```
steps = request.POST.getlist('steps')
```

[doc is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

Answer (score 2):

First, what I would send in the `data` attribute of the AJAX request would be `JSON.stringify({...})` of what you are sending now.

Then, on the python code, I would do : `import json; json.loads(request.body)` and that would give you the initial JS dictionary in python. Then you can use it as a normal dictionary.

Also `step` is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) so the right way to print it would be `print(step['title'])` instead of `print(step.title)`

edit: 
If the json string is not plain ASCII, you might need to decode it first using something like : `json.loads(request.body.decode(), encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: I tested the way you suggest, but I got an error message.   Exception Value: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
Request information:
GET: No GET data

POST:
{"id":"111","title":"ttt","description":"desc","steps":[{"title":"1"},{"title":"2"},{"title":"3"}]} = ''

Comment: Did you used `json.loads(request.body)` instead of `request.POST` in your python code ?

Comment: json.loads(request.body.decode(), encoding='utf-8') is works for me

Comment: If this works for you, can you mark the answer as the solution ?